# Why is there no kernel for the armhf architecture available in the Debian repositories?

Tags: linux, debian, arm

I tried searching packages.debian.org for "linux-image" in the stable distribution for the armhf architecture. [See here for my exact query](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&arch=armhf&searchon=names&keywords=linux-image). There are no results.

Is Linux not included in Debian for the ARM architecture? Why not?